# No matching distribution found for botocore<1.22.0,>=1.21.0 (from awsebcli)

Tags: python, pip, circleci, botocore

CircleCi returns the following error:

No matching distribution found for botocore <1.22.0,> = 1.21.0 (from awsebcli).

[image]

My config.yml file installs the following dependencies:

- sudo apt-get -y -qq update
- sudo apt-get install python3-pip python-dev build-essential
- sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
- sudo pip3 install awsebcli --upgrade pip3 install awscli

Answer (score 14):

In my case, the issue is that I have two python versions installed. So using python3 worked smoothly

```
python3 ./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/ebcli_installer.py
```

Answer (score 2):

These commands work for me:

```
- apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-dev
- apt install python3 -y
- apt install python3-pip -y
- export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
- pip3 install awsebcli --upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on a docker container provided by aws:  `FROM amazon/aws-cli` the python version is: `2.7.18`

In that case, if you see this error:

```
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.
```

I used this to fix it:

```
pip install awsebcli botocore==1.19.63 --upgrade --use-feature=2020-resolver
```

**1.19.63** could be different in your case

Comment: It tried to install but errored out before completion:

ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been raised [upstream](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/issues/87). The suggested workaround from there is `sudo pip3 install awsebcli botocore==1.19.63 --upgrade`.